# Linq through multiple object classes

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new with Linq and cannot find a similar topic..
I'm trying to show only organizations where the current authenticated user is present.

I have the following Linq, but the returned organizations are incorrect :

```
OrganizationList.DataSource = from i in Database<Organization>.Linq()
where (i.Users.Select(y => y.User.Id).Contains(user_id))
select i;
```

Here are the classes :

```
public class Organization
{
    int Id
    string Name
    IList<OrganizationUser> Users
    [...]
}

OrganizationUser
{
    int Id
    User User
    Organization Organization
    [...]
}

User
{
    int Id
    string FirstName
    string LastName
    [...]
}
```

Assuming :

```
Database<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

user_id is the current authenticated user id

I am using NHibernate

I cannot modify the classes, so OrganizationUser must be used.

Could you please help me ?

---

Edit :
Thank you very much for your help !

Both of these solutions are working :

```
OrganizationList.DataSource = Database<Organization>.Linq()
                             .Where(o => o.Users.Any(u => u.User.Id == user_id));


OrganizationList.DataSource = from i in Database<Organization>.Linq()
                              where (i.Users.Any(y => y.User.Id == user_id)
                              select i;
```

Thanx again :)

Comment: **HOW** are the results incorrect. Other than `Could you please help me?`, I don't see question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have the chance to test it but the following may work;

```
OrganizationList.DataSource = from i in Database<Organization>.Linq()
where (i.Users.Any(y => y.User.Id == user_id)
select i;
```

Comment: That should yield the same result as the query the OP already has.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Actually this is comparing the `user_id` to the `ID` in the `User` table whereas the OP is comparing it to the `ID` in the `OrganizationUser` table.  It's very likely those ids are different.

Comment: @juharr: That's not correct. Please check again. Both queries start with `Organization` and continue to `Users` and finally `User`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth My bad.  I guess I was blinded by the many-to-many table having an unnecessary id column.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
var organizationsWithUser = Database<Organization>.Linq()
                           .Where(o => o.Users.Any(u => u.User.Id == user_id));
```

Comment: That should yield the same result as the query the OP already has.

Comment: This solution works with a small change : .Any(u => u.User.Id == user_id)